# Fast sine/cosine for ARMv7+NEON: looking for testers…

Tags: performance, assembly, arm, iphone-3gs, neon

Could somebody with access to an iPhone 3GS or a Pandora please test the following assembly routine I just wrote?

It is supposed to compute sines and cosines really really fast on the NEON vector FPU. I know it compiles fine, but without adequate hardware I can't test it. If you could just compute a few sines and cosines and compare the results with those of sinf() and cosf() it would really help.

Thanks!

```
#include <math.h>

/// Computes the sine and cosine of two angles
/// in: angles = Two angles, expressed in radians, in the [-PI,PI] range.
/// out: results = vector containing [sin(angles[0]),cos(angles[0]),sin(angles[1]),cos(angles[1])]
static inline void vsincos(const float angles[2], float results[4]) {
    static const float constants[]  = { 
    /* q1 */  0,                M_PI_2,           0,                M_PI_2,
    /* q2 */  M_PI,             M_PI,             M_PI,             M_PI,
    /* q3 */  4.f/M_PI,         4.f/M_PI,         4.f/M_PI,         4.f/M_PI,
    /* q4 */ -4.f/(M_PI*M_PI), -4.f/(M_PI*M_PI), -4.f/(M_PI*M_PI), -4.f/(M_PI*M_PI),
    /* q5 */  2.f,              2.f,              2.f,              2.f,
    /* q6 */  .225f,            .225f,            .225f,            .225f
    };  
    asm volatile(
        // Load q0 with [angle1,angle1,angle2,angle2]
        "vldmia %1, { d3 }\n\t"
        "vdup.f32 d0, d3[0]\n\t"
        "vdup.f32 d1, d3[1]\n\t"
        // Load q1-q6 with constants
        "vldmia %2, { q1-q6 }\n\t"
        // Cos(x) = Sin(x+PI/2), so
        // q0 = [angle1, angle1+PI/2, angle2, angle2+PI/2]
        "vadd.f32 q0,q0,q1\n\t"
        // if angle1+PI/2>PI, substract 2*PI
        // q0-=(q0>PI)?2*PI:0
        "vcge.f32 q1,q0,q2\n\t"
        "vand.f32 q1,q1,q2\n\t"
        "vmls.f32 q0,q1,q5\n\t"
        // q0=(4/PI)*q0 - q0*abs(q0)*4/(PI*PI)
        "vabs.f32 q1,q0\n\t"
        "vmul.f32 q1,q0,q1\n\t"
        "vmul.f32 q0,q0,q3\n\t"
        "vmul.f32 q1,q1,q4\n\t"
        "vadd.f32 q0,q0,q1\n\t"
        // q0+=.225*(q0*abs(q0) - q0)
        "vabs.f32 q1,q0\n\t"
        "vmul.f32 q1,q0,q1\n\t"
        "vsub.f32 q1,q0\n\t"
        "vmla.f32 q0,q1,q6\n\t"
        "vstmia %0, { q0 }\n\t"
        :: "r"(results), "r"(angles), "r"(constants)
        : "memory","cc","q0","q1","q2","q3","q4","q5","q6"
    );  
}
```

Comment: Just curious -- what algorithm are you using to fast-compute the sin,cos?

Comment: if you add a test program I can run it on my beagleboard.. Same CPU.

Comment: @gahooa: I use the method described by Nicolas Capens on http://www.devmaster.net/forums/showthread.php?t=5784
and the fact that cos(x)=sin(x+90°)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just tested it on my beagleboard.. As said in the comments: Same CPU.

Your code is roughly 15 times faster than the clib.. Well done!

I've measured 82 cycles for each call of your implementation and 1260 for the four c-lib calls. Note that I've compiled with soft-float ABI and my OMAP3 is early silicon, so each call to the the c-lib version has a NEON stall of at least 40 cycles.

I've zipped together the results..

http://torus.untergrund.net/code/sincos.zip

The performance-counter stuff will most likely not work on the iphone.

Hope that's what you've been looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much Nils. I'm a bit surprised it worked out of the box, actually :-) The same method implemented for the VFP11 is only about twice as fast as calling sinf()+cosf() on my iPod Touch, so I used a lookup table instead.

Comment: Ah I see from your test program that you used the double precision variant of the libc function (sin()/cos(), not sinf()/cosf()). That explains why the libc functions performed so poorly I think :-)

Comment: Just compiled and run it with sinf/cosf, and it does not make much of a difference.

Comment: Do you mean, there is almost no difference in results compared to when testing with sin()/cos(), versus sinf()/cosf(), or there is almost no difference in speed between my function and libc's?

Comment: There is not much difference between sin and sinf (same for cos). I measure 1260 cycles/interation for the double-version and 1245 cycles/iteration for the float version. I bet it's the same code and we just save the cast from double to float.

Comment: Using soft-float when compiling is like running it without floating point hardware. All floating point operations are simulated with integer arithmetics instructions, which would give you probably 10x worse performance.

Answer (score 3):

Oh - before I forget it: Maybe you can safe yourself a bit of work..

Take a look at these NEON optimized math functions:

http://code.google.com/p/math-neon/

Comment: Yes I know these functions. I wish I had an iPhone 3GS for playing with NEON, which surely is much more fun than working on my iPod's VFP11. With the iPhone a FPU craze started, but before that the rule was: DON'T do floats, DO fixed point. I'm starting to think the guys coding with floats for the iPhone are wrong. ARM is really good with integers, and setting up float registers has a large overhead.

Comment: In fact I know another related project, not this one. The one I had in mind had only matrix/vector functions.
Just checked the one you put a link to. It looks like it has all the math.h functions! I'm starring it, thanks! :-)